# Form counting every record when clicking submit?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form that im outputting results of comments, it can more than one.
I can aprrove these comments all at once, but what I'm trying to do is make it
with the option to submit 1 comment at a time or all comments at a time.
The form at first I wrote it to work on 'submit all', so now with adding a submit
per comment also, I get some errors.

I get because every time I submit a comment (1 comment) its still looking for all the other comments
which I did not submit. 
What I think is doing since txtTotalRecords= Mush2.Recordcount, it trying to find the 
other records which weren't submitted.
I just can't figure out how I can change this to make it work.

Doing a cfdump on the form i get, meaning there are 11 comments to submit.
[image]

How would I be able to change  RecordCount to take in every record by itself?

```
<cfparam name="FormSubmit" type="string" default="FormNotSubmitted">
<cfif isDefined("form.submit")><cfset FormSubmit = "FormSubmitted"></cfif>
<cfif isDefined("form.submit1")><cfset FormSubmit = "FormSubmitted1"></cfif>
<!--- Begin Content ================================================== --->
<cfif FormSubmit eq "FormNotSubmitted" || FormSubmit eq "FormNotSubmitted1" >
<form method="post" action="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm" name="review_comments">
<cfoutput>
<input type="hidden" name="txtApprovedBy" value="#GetCurrentUser.emp_id#">
<!-- count the records that come in from the pending -->

</cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="Mush3">
<form method="post" action="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm" name="review_onecomment">
<input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#Mush2.Recordcount#">
    <hr>
        <div class="comments_approvaldecision">
            <p>

            <CFDUMP VAR=#response_id#>
            <input type="hidden" name="txtResponseID#mush2.CurrentRow#" value="#response_id#">
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#mush2.CurrentRow#" id="approve#CurrentRow#" value="1" checked="checked"> <label for="approve#CurrentRow#">Approve</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#mush2.CurrentRow#" id="deny#CurrentRow#" value="2"> <label for="deny#CurrentRow#">Deny</label>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            <input type="radio" name="star#mush2.CurrentRow#" id="givestar#mush2.CurrentRow#" value="0" checked="checked"> <label for="givestar#CurrentRow#"></i> Give Star!</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="star#mush2.CurrentRow#" id="denystar#mush2.CurrentRow#" value="1"> <label for="denystar#CurrentRow#"></i> No Star</label>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit">
</form>
</cfoutput>

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>

</cfif>
<cfdump var="#form#">

<cfif FormSubmit eq "FormSubmitted" || FormSubmit eq "FormSubmitted1">
    <!--- Get Form Values --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#txtTotalRecords#" index="j">
    <h2>test</h2>
        <cfset  response_id[j]  = #Trim(form["txtResponseID" & j])#>
        <cfset  execoffice_status[j]    = #Trim(form["execoffice_status" & j])#>
        <cfset  star[j] = #Trim(form["star" & j])#>
        <cfset  commentpositive[j]  = #Trim(form["txtCommentPositive" & j])#>
        <cfset  commentnegative[j]  = #Trim(form["txtCommentNegative" & j])#>
        <cfset  commentpositivereReplace[j] = reReplace(commentpositive[j], '\n', '<br>', 'ALL')>
        <cfset  commentnegativereReplace[j] = reReplace(commentnegative[j], '\n', '<br>', 'ALL')>
    </cfloop>
 ......... more code...
```

Comment: Do you mean to be mixing Mush3 and Mush2 queries? They way you have it nested, you're creating as many forms as there are records in your Mush3 query, but you're referencing a `#currentrow#` variable from mush2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code you are getting errors on is not in your sample code listed on this page.

I'm assuming you are doing a to/from loop based upon form.txtTotalRecords.

What you'll want to do is loop over your form items looking for a specific partial form name.

something like this:

```
<cfloop list="form.fieldnames" index="i">
    <cfif left(i,13) IS "txtResponseID">
        <cfset thisID = replaceNoCase(i,"txtResponseID","")>
        <cfquery>
            UPDATE myTable
            SET approve = <cfqueryparam value="#form["execoffice_status" & thisID]#">
            WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#thisID">
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: i think you may be right and have to make more changes